# How to create a table in R that displays the percentage of observations per year equal to a certain value?

Tags: r, dplyr, group

I'm working with a time series dataset on levels of opposition in authoritarian regimes. I've included a sample of the data below. I would like to produce a table that displays the percentage of countries per year with a value of `1` for `v2psoppaut`. Could someone tell me how to go about doing this? I'd like to produce a table that I can save as a new `df` for plotting.

```
structure(list(year = 1900:1905, COWcode = c(70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 
70L, 70L), country_name = c("Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", 
"Mexico", "Mexico"), country_text_id = c("MEX", "MEX", "MEX", 
"MEX", "MEX", "MEX"), v2x_regime = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    v2psoppaut_ord = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using `dplyr` from `tidyverse` to group your data by year, then summarize it (aggregate) by taking the sum of rows where `v2psoppaut_ord` is equal to 1 divided by the total number of rows within that group (e.g. year) with the `n()` function. Save that to a new df for plotting. You will have two values: year and auth, with the latter indicating the proportion (multiply by 100 to get percentage) of countries with a value of 1 for the variable you indicated. Don't forget to ungroup the data with `ungroup()`

```
library(tidyverse)

plot_df <- df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(auth = sum(v2psoppaut_ord == 1, na.rm = T) / n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you know why the `auth` column would be filled with `NA` when I run the code you've provided?

Comment: Yes; see the edit. There are `NA` values in the column you are trying to sum and R doesnt know what to do with them (it can't 'sum' missing values so it doesnt assume for you that you want it to). You can tell R to ignore `NA` values with `na.rm = T`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when you group by year you only have **one observation per country** then you could do something like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarize(prop = sum(v2psoppaut_ord == 1)/n())
```

Here `prop` is the proportion of `v2psoppaut_ord == 1` out of the number of rows in the group. If the rows in the group are the countries, then this would give you what you're looking for. Your data should look something like this for this to work:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c(rep(1900,3),rep(1901,3),rep(1902,3)), 
                 country_name = c(rep(c("Mexico", "Canada", "US"),3)), 
                 v2psoppaut_ord = c(sample(1:4,9,replace = T)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Do you know why the `prop` column would be filled with `NA`?

Comment: If there are NA values in `v2psoppaut_ord`  then `prop` will be NA. You can do this `summarize(prop = sum(v2psoppaut_ord == 1, na.rm = TRUE)/n())` That will omit all the NAs. But when analyzing the proportion you need to remember that it does not take into account countries without data.